# Why are there two ways of using in c#

Tags: c#

Please forgive me I'm a self educated c# coder, I never learned coding at a school. And sometimes i miss the terminology or logic behind common practices. I am wondered about the "using" keyword in C#.

using can be placed in the header of a program like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
```

But I also see it sometimes "inline" like below. I say inline and that's probably a wrong term, but I don't know how this is called

```
using (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(saveSettingsDialog.FileName)) 
{ 
//code to be placed to do something (in this case fill an xml)
}
```

Thinking about code design, I wonder when is it preferred to use the "inline" syntax. And does it provide some extra benefit ?

Comment: There are actually 3 ways now with the new static using in C#6, but lets focus on the two you're asking about.

Comment: The first is the [using directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) the other is the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: `this` can also mean multiple things, depending on context.

Comment: When should i use "using" as directive  or as statement

Comment: You should do what you want. The two as totally different and only share the same name by chance.